# Angular JS not working in subpages

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a HTML page that works as a container of different HTML sub-pages/Usercontrols. 
I use Ajax get of jquery to load the HTML of the sub page in the container page.
I am using a angular js directive in one of the sub pages.
The angular js directive is not working in the sub page and the potential issue can be that my anguarl js is firing before the HTML of the subpage gets loaded into the container page. And thats why angular js dont see the directive in the subpage it needs to process.

Is there a way to delay the execution of the angular js until subpage gets loaded.

Comment: Don't use jQuery ajax. Use Angular's `$http` service. The issue is that Angular doesn't know about the ajax call, so you would have to use `$scope.$apply()` to let Angular know. Further, you can just use `ng-include` rather than make an ajax call manually.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @m59's assessment, but if you are unable to follow that route you will need to use the manual bootstrapping [see manual initialization](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)